# leave two columns in flex-end

Tags: react-bootstrap

my code is this

```
<Container style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: '0px', width: '100%', left: 0, right: 0}}  fluid>
    <Row >

          <Col className={sizeWidth < 650 ? "d-flex justify-content-center" : "d-flex justify-content-end"}>
               <ButtonAnterior tabIndex={-1} onClick={() => setCurrentTab('Produto')} text={"anterior"} />
          </Col>

         <Col className={sizeWidth < 650 ? "d-flex justify-content-center" : "d-flex justify-content-end"}>
           <ButtonProximo onClick={() => setCurrentTab('Pontos')} text={"proximo"} />

         </Col>

    </Row>
</Container>
```

the result looks like this

[image]

I need to put both with flex-end, the styles that were added in the container are necessary because the buttons are centered for smartphone

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is overusing Grid. It's not needed. What happening here is, that by using Row/Col the width is divided by half and every button is positioned at the end of it.

Instead just use the Stack component (=flexbox):

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/stack/

```
<Stack direction="horizontal" gap={2} className="justify-content-end">...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, not known 'stack', I will learn about it

Comment: So, did it solved the problem? If so, please mark the question as solved